# How to restrict snakejobs to a specific node using --slurm?

Tags: slurm, snakemake, hpc

I am using snakemake to execute my workflow.
Here is my command:

```
snakemake -s /path/to/Snakefile --slurm --jobs 50 --use-conda
```

However, this command submits jobs to all nodes. How can I provide names of nodes that should be used for job submission or names of nodes that should be excluded?

The jobs should be running on specific nodes

Comment: If you already know how to choose nodes using `sbatch`, a custom `sbatch` command can be included using the `--cluster` option of snakemake.

Comment: If the target nodes form a particular partition, adding --default-resources slurm_partition=<partition> should work, if you want to reuse that this can also be set for all your jobs in a configuration profile.

Comment: thanks for the comments.
@Robert: This only works when deleting the --slurm flag: "snakemake  --jobs 5--use-conda --cluster "sbatch --nodelist". But then, my resource allocations in the snakemake rules are ignored. A job will block the complete node (job is assigned 1 core and all the memory available on that node)

Comment: @daVinci: Unfortunatey, the nodes do not form a specific partition and I did not find a way to specify a single node using --default-resources

Comment: To include resources with `--cluster` you can use (for example) `--cluster "sbatch -t {resources.time} --mem={resources.mem}"`